# View diffs of 'binary' files on svn log --diff

Tags: svn

I have a number of XML files in SVN which I'd like to get the full log with diffs for. At some point they had an SVN mime-type of application/xml. This means that when I try to run `svn log --diff` on them, some older revisions will just say

```
Cannot display: file marked as a binary type.
svn:mime-type = application/xml
```

If using an individual diff, I can view it by using `--force` so it will show anyway, but this option doesn't have the same effect on `svn log`. I've also tried overriding `--diff-cmd` to use `diff` externally where I could pass the text option, but the override does not have any effect in `svn log` - or in `svn diff` when specifying a revision for that matter.

Any suggestions to view the diffs?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Indeed, there are solutions for new files, but the mimetype was bad in older commits, and was fixed in a newer one.

Comment: Perhaps there's something similar to [bfg repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) for SVN? The you could apply the solution for new files on the older commits and rewrite history.

Comment: In the end I've gone with just getting the diffs individually which has proved to not be *too* slow for my application. Investigating fixing it historically isn't worth it at this stage as we are migrating the repo to git in a few weeks anyway